# PowerBi - Current Week

Tags: week-number

I have a Multi-row card where it shows how many `CLL, PLL, and KG` our warehouse have packed "today".

However I would like to have similar card which sums up the current week.
(Meant as a fun fact for our warehouse)
But i'm struggling with making a filter from where it only shows the current week.

The filter I made to get "today" is pretty basic (not pretty, but it works)

```
Gettoday = IF('Date'[Date]=TODAY(),"Yes","No")
```

I have tried making similar with week instead but it don't seem to work.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you can do, to fit your approach (assuming you're using a calculated column here) would be something like:

```
get_current_week = IF(
    AND(
    WEEKNUM(TODAY()) = WEEKNUM('Date'[Date]),
    YEAR(TODAY()) = YEAR('Date'[Date])
    ),
    "Yes",
    "No"
)
```

basically you compare year & weeknum of today, to your date value's:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/weeknum-function-dax

i would recommend, that you check out the microsoft reference on datefunctions because there's bound to be a more elegant way to setting that filter.

Comment: Thank you that worked.
I know it's not very elegent, but it works :-)

Comment: glad to hear that - and we've all been there ;)